# not able to migrate from websphere standalone application to tomcat web application using jsp and servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere

I am facing problem in this line when i tried to run my application using my tomcat server (using jsp and servlet).. exception which i am facing is noclassfound exception..but when i tried to run the same code as a standalone application it is getting executed. As my local tomcat server could not load the websphere context and the respective jar it is showing this error. How to load the context and respective jar in my tomcat server.. kindly proved a solution for this..thanks in advance

```
             System.getProperties().put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        System.getProperties().put("java.naming.provider.url", DBPropertiesLoader.TI_EJB_URL);


        System.getProperties().put("java.naming.provider.url", ejbClientUrl);

        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        Object ejbObject = ctx.lookup("ejb/EnigmaServiceAccess");
```

Comment: tomcat has its own JNDI provider so it will not allow to provide its own one. You need to configure your resources using tomcat resource description in server.xml (or your application context.xml).

Comment: i did my jndi configuration in server.xml already. how to provide the provider to tomcat server